# ¿Pre cargar datos en spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

estoy comenzando con un proyecto y quiero que al iniciar el aplicativo haga inserciones a algunas tablas,lo haría en la propia BD pero tengo atributos `"created_At"` y `"update_At"`:

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.EntityListeners;
import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        value={"cratedAt","updateAt"},
        allowGetters=true

        )

public abstract class AuditModel {
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="created_at",nullable=false,updatable=false)
@CreatedDate()
private Date createdAt;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name="update_at",nullable=false)
@LastModifiedDate
private Date updateAt;

public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
    this.createdAt = createdAt;
}

public Date getUpdateAt() {
    return updateAt;
}

public void setUpdateAt(Date updateAt) {
    this.updateAt = updateAt;
}

}
```

lo cual heredo a todos mis entidades.
spring boot maneja las inserciones a estos atributos, alguna forma de realizar la pre-insercion?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes probar implementando la interfaz ApplicationRunner, todo lo que pongas en el método run se ejecutará al inicializar el contexto de spring.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationRunner.html

```
@Configuration
public class OnBoot implements ApplicationRunner{

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        //tu lógica
    }
}
```